# Recursive DAX Formula help needed

Tags: dax

I have tried to do some research, but cannot find the answer I am looking for. I have a table that has recipes. Some recipes use portions of other recipes in the same table. See below. P-salt is a house seasoning, and it is used in other recipes. Some recipes go as far as 3-5 iterations deep before finding the original ingredient.

[Picture of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4iOg.png)

| Batch Item | Ingredient | Amount | UOM | Batch Yield | Batch UOM | Item Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marinade | Buttermilk | 64 | floz | 68 | floz | 3.47 |
| Marinade | P-Salt | 4 | floz | 68 | floz | **1.29** |
| Fillet | Chicken Fillet | 25 | Each | 25 | Each | 1.74 |
| Fillet | Marinade | 68 | fl oz | 25 | Each | **1.74** |
| P-Salt | Black Pepper | 8 | floz | 64 | floz | 3.55 |
| P-Salt | Granulated Garlic | 16 | floz | 64 | floz | 7.88 |
| P-Salt | Paprika | 8 | floz | 64 | floz | 3.71 |
| P-Salt | Onion Powder | 8 | floz | 64 | floz | 5.08 |
| P-Salt | Salt | 16 | floz | 64 | floz | 0.35 |

You will see that P-Salt is involved in other recipes, including the Marinade. The marinade is used in turn as a part of the fillet recipe. I am trying to create a measure that uses this table to find out (for example) how much Black Pepper would be used in the full recipe for marinated chicken. Math says it should be 68 (total ounces in final recipe) / 68 (total yield from the recipe that matches) * 8 (amount of black pepper that yields the full batch). I will then use the amount used in each recipe to calculate a total cost in each recipe. The two bolded cells in the table above shows the calculation I am struggling to make ultimately.

I have it working now with calculated columns to get to the second layered recipe and sum that together. I cannot figure out how to make it keep digging deeper until it doesn't need to. Most recipes will only go one layer deep, but many will need to go beyond that. How can I get a measure that digs x layers deep to find the amount of the base ingredient used?

Comment: Please share your dataset as copiable text, not as image.

Comment: Please share your dataset in Excel file as copiable text, not as image. then will gladly help you.

Comment: Updated. Looking forward to seeing what you have in mind for a solution!